# How to pull untracked files with git

Tags: git, gitlab

The title may not be clear but my issue is, I have a laravel project on gitlab. I cloned the project from the master branch then after running `composer install` I realized that the bootstrap/autoload.php file was missing.

But on the develop branch it is there. I merged the develop branch into master but it is not getting the bootstrap/autoload.php file. I noticed that the last commit on that file was a year ago, so it has been missing for a while, I just didn't notice.

I also noticed that there were other files on the develop branch that were not getting merged into master.

I checked all my .gitignore files to see if the corresponding files were added but that's not the case because they wouldn't be on gitlab on the develop branch in the first place.

When I run `git status` on master it says It is up to date. How do I get those missing  files merged into master.

Comment: Have the files ever been in the master branch? If you diff both branches what does it say?

Comment: @DorShinar When I run `git diff master..develop` I get `fatal: ambiguous argument 'master..develop': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'`

Comment: Try running `git diff develop...master` and make sure you fetched both beforehand

Comment: @DorShinar I did `git fetch origin develop` then `git diff develop...master` and still got the same error

Comment: @DorShinar I tried `git diff development...master --` but got `fatal: bad revision 'development...master'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by checking out all the files from the develop branch to master branch:

`git checkout origin/development -- .`

This gave me all the files that were missing from master but were in develop